# How to make my python executable to run on startup in fedora 23?

Tags: python, authentication, startup, fedora, fedora-23

I have used `pyinstaller` to make my script executable and now I want it to run on every login/startup. The gnome tweak tool is not listing my executable. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The best answer here might actually depend on what, exactly, your script does. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @mattdm My script scraps some data from a webpage and send the information as a sms at startup, automatically.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you want to trigger on? Every time a user is logged in, every time a specific user logs in, every time the machine is rebooted, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking 3 questions here. Startup and login are not the same.

1) To have a script run on login you might add it to .bash_profile (hidden file in your user's home directory):
https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/35263/execute-shell-script-at-login/

2) To have the script run on startup (boot) you may choose to create an /etc/rc.local file (https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/26898/what-is-the-auto-start-file-like-rclocal/)
make sure it is executable:

```
chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

enable the service:

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

3) Run 'gnome-session-properties' and add your script there.